# Maven : How do I build a Java Application with structure like Jboss , Tomcat...?

Tags: maven-3, maven-release-plugin

How do I build a Java Application with structure like Jboss , Tomcat...?

I have a default Maven Project -> Simple Project .

I want to have below the structure after being built :

```
    bin
    conf
    lib
    native
    src-c++

    readme.txt
```

bin : all shell files so that I can run jar by shell.
lib : contains all the JARs , with My Java Classes  
It is similar with Jboss , Tomcat.

How to do with Maven , or Maven Plugin?

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this is using [maven assembly plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/). This plugin allows you to create a distribution structured the way you want.  Evidently, all the items that you need to package should either be present in your maven project or available as maven dependencies.